# Why my application class which extends android.app.application is not working?

Tags: java, android, oncreate, android-application-class

I have to call a print method from the test class whenever my application starts. I have called this print method from onCreate() of MyApplication class which extends android.app.application class. In the print() method, I am displaying a toast message. However , that toast message is not getting displayed.Kindly help!

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Test.print(this);
        Toast.makeText(this,"On Create  called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}


public class Test {
    static  void print(Context context)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Print called",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to debug ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also declare your custom Application class in `manifest`:

```
<application
    android:name=".<your packages to the class>.MyApplication"
...>
```