# react-navigation/native-stack not working on Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I get the following error:

```
E/unknown:ReactNative: Exception in native call
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use RNScreens components your app's activity need to extend ReactActivity
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenContainer.setupFragmentManager(ScreenContainer.kt:169)
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenContainer.onAttachedToWindow(ScreenContainer.kt:199)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:21304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4239)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:4246)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:6001)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5777)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5717)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewGroupManager.addView(ViewGroupManager.java:37)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.manageChildren(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:533)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$ManageChildrenOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:217)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:915)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1026)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2600(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:1086)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:29)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:175)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:85)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:997)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:728)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

When I try to change:
`public class RnActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {`
to `public class RnActivity extends ReactActivity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {`, as the error suggests, I get a new error:

```
E/mk_d : Utils: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.rn_management.RnActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.Application cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
```

When I remove react-navigation/native-stack from my RN bundle, everything works just fine.
In addition I receive the following error (is it related?):
 `E/ThemeUtils: View class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextView is and AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React-native-screens is one of the react-navigation dependencies so you need to use it in order to get the navigation to work. Extend your Activity with ReactActivity and create or edit your Application class in native Android code:

```
class YourApplication : Application(), ReactApplication, LifecycleObserver {...}
```

This link here https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps is useful if you want to integrate react-native into already existing app and do not want to implement ReactApplication and ReactActivity.

Comment: I`ve already followed the tutorial (this is how I integrated RN into my existing app). Could you explain the code you wrote? Is that Kotlin?

Comment: Basically you create a new class which extends Application and implements  ReactApplication. Then you must update the maninfest like discribed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58247216/why-my-application-class-which-extends-android-app-application-is-not-working. 
Code snippet is Kotlin yes.

Comment: Combined with the other solution (by Rhyan-WoodsAndWalker), and after I changed `mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(sApp.getApplicationContext());` to `mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);` the problem was solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you on an older version of React Native? check your `android/app/src/main/java/com/(your app)/MainActivity.java` file & change the first class line to extend ReactActivity if it doesn't already -

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
  ...
```

That should satisfy the error you're getting - ReactActivity also [extends a compat class](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java#L21) so it will possibly fix your other issue too

Comment: I changed the RnActivity to extend ReactActivity (instead of MainActivity), it indeed helped. Thank you.